# Why exception exc_bad_access is coming in button clcik in iphone

Tags: iphone, exc-bad-access

I am trying to load my next screen with (nib) file. whenever I am clicking on button I am getting an error EXC_BAD_ACCESS in onjcSend_disassembly_0x0109809b.nasm.

I also see when I  was trying to connect my buutons with FilesOwner in interface builder, I was not getting it to connect. So I connect with function by the "First Responder" option. Why it was not connecting with FilesOwners.

sometimes it being load perfectly but maximum time I am getting error message.

And also please know me about the above error and problem?

I am seeing one error message in interface builder is that "setting does not have outlet view" where Setting is my class name (setting.xib.)

Comment: can you give your button click code ???

Comment: Do you have UIView in your XIB or you just put UIButton and bind that with Files Owner view property ? Can you attache screenshot of your xib file here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are lot of issues in your question

1. Connecting Buttons in Xib
   If you want to connect a button via interfacebuilder you have to declare the button in the .h file as

> **IBOutlet** UIButton *myButton;

This IBOutlet Indicates the Interface Builder that there is going to be a button placed in xib.
   Dont connect anything to the FirstResponder

1. if you see this error "setting does not have outlet view" then in your xib you have removed the outlet connected to you View.
   To Solve this right click the view in you xib and drag the New Referencing Outlet connector to the file owner. then select the view property there.
2. When you touch a button
   You must have a IBAction to the button to assign via Interfacebuilder.
   in your .h

   > -(IBAction) onTouchEvent :(id)sender;

Now rightClick the button in your xib. choose TouchUpInside connector and drag to fileowner you can see the onTouchEvent pops out.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably having problems with retain count. eg. you are trying to reach an object that's released by either autorelease or you. Try re-checking your releases.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have set the class for the File's owner of the nib as the the class in which you have declared the outlet.